# python dataframe time series division into smaller time windows loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, time, series

at the moment I'm trying to do a time series analysis in python. My data is saved as a pandas dataframe, and now I try to calculate e.g. the mean for smaller time windows (for the data in the columns). I directly want to save the new values into an array. If I only had a small dataset I would do it manual like this:

```
dataframe1.values (to convert it into an array)
array2 = np.array(([dataframe1[0:1000].mean()],[dataframe1[1001:2000].mean()]...])
```

Well, but I have a really large dataset, so it would take very long to do it this way by hand. So I thought about solving my problem with a loop, but I don't really know how to do this, when I directly want to save the new values in an array. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Refer [Rolling window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)